# C# - Remove an item from the combobox and add another list for databinding

Tags: c#, sqlite, data-binding, combobox, windows-store-apps

I'm developing an app on windows phone / RT. The purpose of this app is to create a form and be able to save the form to work on it (or on different forms) later.

I have to show a progressbar with the number of fields completed (for example 3/10 fields are completed).

The issue is that I have some comboboxes, and I'm use databinding with a SQLite database.

I do the following steps to check the number of completed fields:

1) When I launch the app, I create a list in the constructor of the page and send it in the combobox like this:

```
List<string> listCombobox = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
nameCombobox.ItemsSource = listCombobox;
nameCombobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

2) In the xaml, I define a combobox with the following properties:

```
<Combobox x:Name="nameCombobox" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=nameInDatabase, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

So now the update works fine, and when I select another save, I retrieve the previous selected item.

BUT until the user changes the item in the combobox, I see that as an uncompleted field (to check if a field is completed or not, I take the data from the database, and when a column is completed, I say that the field is completed). 
The issue is if the user wants the first item, he won't change the combobox, so the field will be considered as uncompleted.

My question is:
Is it possible to show a message in the combobox like "Please make a choice" and remove it when the user change the combobox, knowing I use a databinding with my local database (SQLite)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following link to show the place holder text in ComboBox,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.placeholdertext

Regards,
Riyaj Ahamed I